# PHP Directory iterator from array and return newest file in each directory

Tags: php

I am very green on coding but i am learning, my project is to display motion events from my camera feeds to a web page. Currently all camera record to my ftp and its working great but sorting thru all the files is a mess.
I am trying to retrieve the most recent video from each of the directories (4). This is what i have put together thus far, it returns each directory but only gets most recent file from the first directory... i am assuming that the foreach is not working?

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$mostRecentFilePath = "";
$mostRecentFileMTime = 0;


$dirs = array_filter(glob('/www/public/cctv/*'), 'is_dir');

foreach ($dirs as &$value) {
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($value), RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);



foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        if ($fileinfo->getMTime() > $mostRecentFileMTime) {
            $mostRecentFileMTime = $fileinfo->getMTime();
            $mostRecentFilePath = $fileinfo->getPathname();
            $gettextension = $fileinfo->getExtension();
            $trimpath = substr( $mostRecentFilePath, 11);
        }
    }

}

echo '<b>' . $value . '<br>';

 echo '</b>' . $mostRecentFilePath. '<br>';
}


?>
```

And this is the output:

```
/www/public/cctv/BackyardEast
/www/public/cctv/BackyardEast/2020/11/20/BackyardEast_01_20201120141437.mp4
/www/public/cctv/BackyardWest
/www/public/cctv/BackyardEast/2020/11/20/BackyardEast_01_20201120141437.mp4
/www/public/cctv/DrivewayNorth
/www/public/cctv/BackyardEast/2020/11/20/BackyardEast_01_20201120141437.mp4
/www/public/cctv/DrivewaySouth
/www/public/cctv/BackyardEast/2020/11/20/BackyardEast_01_20201120141437.mp4
```

Comment: Your (second) `echo` looks like it should be inside the inner foreach statement, `$mostRecentFilePath` is being set multiple times in the inner `foreach` but is only being output once after the foreach has looped.

Comment: Moving the second echo to the inner foreach gives me all files in the first directory (/www/public/cctv/BackyardEast) only. I assume its not iterating thru the directory array ($dirs)?

Comment: So how many files do you want? The most recent four(4)? You need to restructure your variable as an array (list) rather than as a single value, or otherwise add a counter to escape the `foreach` after X values.

Comment: Thanks for your patience Martin. I am looking for the newest file in each of the 4 directories. Which variable should i make an array (list), sorry my limitations are obvious.